# Allign UIViews differnt when some UIViews are hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I have the following view layouted with autolayout.

```
--------


 +


--------
```

The plus icon is centered vertically on the cell. This should be different when a second icon appears as you can see on the following image:

```
--------


 +

 X

--------
```

I this case both icons together should be alligined vertically centered with a space of 5 between them.

I create my constraints in code no interface builder or Storyboard.

**How can I achieve this with autolayout?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, but you need some code

1. Create outlet for constraint, which align your '+' vertically
2. Change 'constant' property when 'X' appears on your cell

for example

```
{
        if (cell.secondView.hidden == true) {
        // someConstraint - is your align constrain, which you can create throw IB
            cell.someConstraint.constant = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          // note 'minus' - to move first view up
             cell.someConstraint.constant = -cell.secondView.frame.height
        }
}
```

Comment: No outlets please I do not use interface builder.

Comment: if you create constraints programatically, create property for constraint